# How to copy a certain number of chars from a file to a vector the STL-way?

Tags: c++, stl

If I want to copy the contents of a file to a vector, I can do it like that:

```
std::ifstream file("path_to_file");
std::vector<char> buffer(std::istream_iterator<char>(file), 
                         std::istream_iterator<char>());
```

My question is, how would I do this if I want to copy only the first `n` chars?

**Edit** I could write my own version of [`copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/), but is there a way to do this using only existing components?

Comment: Not beautiful but could use replace_copy_if, use the predicate to check if you have copied n chars !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was noted by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829885/how-to-copy-a-certain-number-of-chars-from-a-file-to-a-vector-the-stl-way/3830107#3830107), this would need [`copy_n()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy_n.html), which, due to an oversight, isn't in the current standard library, but will be in C++1x. You can implement one yourself easily, here's one I believe to be correct:

```
template<class InIt, class OutIt> 
OutIt copy_n(InIt src, OutIt dest, size_t n) 
{
  if (!n) return dest;
  *dest = *src;
  while (--n)
    *++dest = *++src;
  return ++dest; 
}
```

Note that `std::copy_n()` presumes the input iterator to be able to deliver `n` objects. When reading from a file, this could be problematic.

---

Absent of `std::copy_n()`, you could use `std::generate_n`.

```
template< typename InIt >
struct input_generator {
  typedef std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type value_type;

  input_generator(InIt begin, InIt end) begin_(begin), end_(end) {}

  value_type operator()()
  {
    assert(it_ != end);
    return *it_++;
  }

  Init begin_;
  Init end_;
};


std::vector<char> buffer;
buffer.reserve(42);

std::generate_n( std::back_inserter(buffer)
               , 42
               , input_generator(std::istream_iterator<char>(file))
               , input_generator(std::istream_iterator<char>()) );
```

---

However, I don't see this as an advantage over reading directly from the file as [avakar showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829885/how-to-copy-a-certain-number-of-chars-from-a-file-to-a-vector-the-stl-way/3830354#3830354).

Comment: Sbi's implementation was not correct for stream iterators, which read from the stream on both increment and initialization. I fixed it.

Comment: @Don: Thanks. That's the reason why even such simple algorithms should be in the std lab — it's easy to let subtle bugs slip even into the most simple ones.

Answer (score 8):

As Alexander points out, the fastest way would be

```
std::vector<char> buffer(n);
file.read(&buffer[0], n);
```

In C++0x, you can use `buffer.data()` instead of `&buffer[0]`; the latter has undefined behavior if `n == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The "STL way" is to use `copy_n`, which is in the STL but not the C++ standard.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but not advisable if portability is a concern. Also, is this added to the standard in C++x0?

Comment: Yes, it's in C++0x. If portability is a concern, then don't do things the STL way, do them the C++ standard way ;-) In this case that probably means just implement copy_n yourself, in your own namespace, perhaps by taking an implementation from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *buffer = new char[n];
file.read(buffer,n);
std::vector<char> myVector
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) myVector.push_back(buffer[i]);
delete [] buffer;

// myVector now holds the first n bytes of file.
```

It may not be the prettiest or quickest way, but it is how I would do it.

Comment: A shorter one would be just to do `std::vector<char> myVector(buffer, n);`

Comment: that should be `std::vector<char> myVector(buffer, buffer+n);` (and skip the forloop)

Comment: What's wrong with reading directly into a (sufficiently resized) vector?

Answer (score 0):

Credit due to @sbi, I forgot about `generate_n`.

The `streambuf` inside `file` has a function `snextc` which returns the next character, qualifying it as a generator function, once its implicit `this` argument is bound.

```
generate_n( back_inserter( buffer ), 42,
            tr1::bind( tr1::mem_fn( &streambuf::snextc ), file.rdbuf() ) );
```

For `vector`, just read directly. This is good for `deque` or whatever.