# How do I use for_each to output to cout?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, cout

Is there a more straight-forward way to do this?

`for_each(v_Numbers.begin(), v_Numbers.end(), bind1st(operator<<, cout));`

Without an explicit `for` loop, if possible.

EDIT:

How to do this for `std::cin` with a `std::vector` if possible? (How to read `n` elements only)?

Comment: Added solution for your edit to my answer.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Edited my edit. Please check.

Comment: Added link for your second edit.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could achieve this using [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) into a [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator):

```
std::vector<int> v_Numbers; // suppose this is the type
// put numbers in
std::copy(v_Numbers.begin(), v_Numbers.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
```

It would be even nicer if you add some suffix:

```
std::copy(v_Numbers.begin(), v_Numbers.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

This assumes that your container is a `vector<int>`, so you will have to replace that part with the appropriate type.

**Edit** regarding reading input:

Conversely, you can copy from a range of [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) into a `vector` using [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::vector<int> v_Numbers;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(v_Numbers));
```

If you want to read n elements only, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829885/how-to-copy-a-certain-number-of-chars-from-a-file-to-a-vector-the-stl-way).

Comment: Almost. `ostream_iterator` is a template, you want `std::ostream_iterator<v_Numbers::value_type>(cout)`.

Comment: No problem; I formatted the answer so there's no scroll-bars, I find it easier to read that way. You can disagree and roll-back if you want.

Comment: Sadly, it does not seem to work : `error: v_Numbers cannot appear in a constant-expression`

Comment: @nakiya: An error is only half the information; what's the code? (EDIT: Er, you need to `copy` to output, not `for_each`. Missed that, sorry Space.)

Comment: @nakiya: Indeed, you have to replace `v_Numbers` in the template argument with the type of `v_Numbers` (e.g. `std::vector<int>::value_type`).

Comment: I think you meant `std::copy` there. `for_each` expects an `operator()` that accepts a `v_Numbers::value_type`

Answer (score 10):

Another option — [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/lambda/using_library.html).

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), cout << boost::lambda::_1);
```

Answer (score 8):

Yep, but you must use std::copy algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    // fill a...
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

yup, using lambda expression (C++ 11) we can inline printing of each element of a STL container to cout.

```
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <vector>     // vector
#include <algorithm>  // for_each
#include <iterator>   // istream_iterator
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v(10,2);
   std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i)->void {std::cout << i <<endl;});
   return 0;
}
```

For reading "n" values from cin to vector,

```
 int main()
 {
   std::vector<int> v;

   int elementsToRead;
   cin>>elementsToRead;  // Number of elements to copy

   // Reading from istream
   std::istream_iterator<int> ii2(std::cin);
   std::copy_n(ii2, elementsToRead, std::back_inserter(v));

   // printing updated vector
   std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i)->void {cout << i <<endl;});

   return 0;
}
```

(or) by using Lambda expression

```
std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>(cin),std::istream_iterator<int>(),[&v](int i)->void { v.push_back(i);});
```

To know more about Lambda expression @ [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: you meant `std::endl`

Answer (score 0):

Not always appropriate in corporate code, but for the sake of enumerating options - if you really find other for_each / std::copy etc. solutions too verbose, you could write:

```
std::ostream& operator(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<My_Type>& v)
{
     // pick one of the other implementations for here...
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<My_Type>(os), std::istream_iterator<My_Type>(),   
          std::back_inserter(v_Numbers));   
}
```

It's much nicer if you're well-mannered (;-p) enough to only overload your specific instantiation of vector (which requires My_Type be more than a typedef to say int, though it's not hard to create a templated class to create new types wrapping an arbitrary type).  Otherwise, if someone else does the same elsewhere in your translation unit, the streaming could become ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I know the `copy` with the iterator is the optimal solution, but just to answer with `for_each`.

You could do:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  locale::global(locale(""));
  wcout::imbue(locale());

  vector<int> vec{1000,2000,3000,4000,5000};
  for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto &x){wcout << x << endl;});
  
  return 0;
}
```

But, for me, it's REALLY much more readable the simple `for` ...

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <locale>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  locale::global(locale(""));
  wcout::imbue(locale());

  vector<int> vec{1000,2000,3000,4000,5000};
  for(auto &v: vec) {
    wcout << v << endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```