# Multiset to vector, C++

Tags: stl, vector, copy, multiset

How to copy last k items from std::multiset in reversed order to std::vector as fast as possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the non-standard `copy_n` (you can easily [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829885/how-to-copy-a-certain-number-of-chars-from-a-file-to-a-vector-the-stl-way)), you can just do this:

```
std::copy_n(your_multiset.rbegin(), k, std::back_inserter(your_vector));
```

`copy_n` is part of C++1x, so there this solution is fully standard. If you want speed, it might be faster to reserve space in the vector in advance to save reallocations.