# passing std::vector to a function which modifies an input array

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector, iterator

I'm using a third-party API ([CryptEncrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379924(VS.85).aspx), to be precise) which takes a C array as an in-out parameter. Logically, the API boils down to the following function:

```
void add1(int *inout, size_t length)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    inout[i] += 1;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid the use of raw arrays, so my question is can I use the std::vector as an input to the API above? Something like the following:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v(10); // vector with 10 zeros
  add1(&v[0], v.size());  // vector with 10 ones?
}
```

Can I use the 'contiguous storage' guarantee of a vector to write data to it? I'm inclined to believe that this is OK (it works with my compiler), but I'd feel a lot better if someone more knowledgeable than me can confirm if such usage doesn't violate the C++ standard guarantees. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of the design-goals of std::vector was that this example should work.

Comment: In the new standard, there is even a `v.data()` member so you don't have to write `&v[0]` anymore: and what could be more clear than `add1(v.data(), v.size());` !

Comment: thanks all for for the answers and comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I use the 'contiguous storage' guarantee of a vector to write data to it?

Yes.

> I'm inclined to believe that this is OK

Your inclination is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's guaranteed that the storage is contiguous (from the 2003 revision of the standard, and even before it was almost impossible to implement sensibly `vector` without using an array under the hood), it should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Storage is guaranteed to be continuous by the standard but accessing element[0] on empty vector is undefined behaviour by the standard. Thus you may get error in some compilers. (See another post that shows this problem with Visual Studio 2010 in [SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829788/using-operator-on-empty-stdvector))

The standard has resolved this in C++0x though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I don't see any problem.