# Calling a C function with the address to an empty std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

If I have a std::vector buffer that has room for 100 characters and I call a C function that will write a NULL terminated string like `writestring(&buffer[0], buffer.size())` from what I've read that's ok if there is already data in buffer. But if the vector is empty the behavior is undefined. How do I get around that, can I write something to the buffer like "qwerty" and then call writestring() so that I know the behavior is always defined? What kind of storage do you guys use when calling C functions? I just read about .data but I don't know how common or portable that is.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you would dynamically allocate your buffer to an a size that isn't a-priori known ahead of time, there's not much gain to using vector over a simple array.

Comment: @CrazyEddie - I disagree. With `std::vector` (or `std::array`) you get [value semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics). I find this decreases stoopid bugs to the point that I *never* use naked arrays or naked pointers to first members.

Comment: You can disagree all you want so long as you realize you're wrong.

Comment: `.data()` is not portable and is basically the equivalent of `&buffer[0]` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.resize(100);
writestring(&v[0], v.size());
```

C

```
void writestring(char*p, size_t len) {
  strncpy(p, "Doofi", len);
}
```

> if the vector is empty the behavior is undefined. How do I get around that?

By passing a non-empty buffer. Use the `.resize()` method to quickly fill the vector, or construct it to be the right size initially: `std::vector<int> v(100);`.

> What kind of storage do you guys use when calling C functions?

`std::vector` is a fine choice for this application. To C, it looks just like an array or a malloc'd region. But, realize that C's pointer is only valid as long as the vector is neither reallocated or destroyed.

Comment: Well check this out I just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829788/using-operator-on-empty-stdvector . Do you agree or disagree? Even if I resize the vector isn't it still empty, and isn't empty behavior undefined?

Comment: A buffer that is `resize`d to a non-zero value is not empty, and taking the address of the first element is valid. A buffer that is `resize`d to zero elements is empty; taking the address of the first element is undefined behavior. As long as `100` != `0`, the above code is well-defined. (Yes, I agree with the conclusion of the referenced question: you mustn't take the address of the first element of an empty vector.)

Answer (score 3):

Resize the vector first:

```
buffer.resize(100);
writestring(buffer.data(), buffer.size());  // buffer.data() == &buffer[0]
```

Alternatively, construct the buffer with the desired size all in one go:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should test that the buffer is not empty.  If it is empty, don't call writestring.